# Access DocumentationComment Node given a DocumentationComment trivia?

Tags: c#, roslyn

[image: Syntax visualizer screenshot]

Having a MethodDeclarationSyntax Node, I'm trying to access its DocumentationCommentSyntax Node.

I can obtain the DocumentationComment trivia by doing this:

```
var firstToken = member.GetFirstToken();
var documentationTrivias = firstToken.LeadingTrivia.Where(t => t.Kind == SyntaxKind.DocumentationComment);
if(documentationTrivias.Count() != 1)
    return null;
var documentationTrivia = documentationTrivias.Single();
```

Now, I would simply need to access the Node that is right under it in the tree. I am convinced it is simple to do, but I can't find a way.

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't use `catch` like that, you should instead explicitly test for `null`.

Comment: Good point, I corrected my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access that node, you need to call `GetStructure()` on the `SyntaxTrivia`. That will return `StructuredTriviaSyntax`, but since you know you have `DocumentationComment`, it will actually be `DocumentationCommentSyntax`, so you can cast it to that.

Also, you don't need to deal with the `FirstToken`, you can use `GetLeadingTrivia()` instead.

```
var documentationCommentTrivia =
    method.GetLeadingTrivia()
          .SingleOrDefault(t => t.Kind == SyntaxKind.DocumentationComment);
if (documentationCommentTrivia.Kind == SyntaxKind.None)
    return null;

var documentationCommentSyntax =
    (DocumentationCommentSyntax)documentationCommentTrivia.GetStructure();
```